# Sharing logic between directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to share the logic between these two directives, I'm still learning Angular and don't quite understand how to accomplish this. I'm getting a *$compile:ctreq* error. I have watched some tutorials and I believe the logic is supposed to be in the controller but I get an error and the page wont load. I have a simple Pomodoro timer and would like the buttons to each be there own directive. Maybe I should be doing this with controllers but either way I would like to know how this works. Thanks..

```
var app = angular.module('pomodoro_timer', ['ui.router', 'firebase']);

app.directive("timer", ['$interval', function($interval) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    controller: function() {

    },

    templateUrl: "/templates/timer.html",
    link: function(scope,element,attributes) {
      scope.intrvl;
      scope.t = 10;
      var tDiv = $(element).find('#time');
      scope.min = "25";
      scope.sec = "00";

      scope.interval = function() {
        scope.intrvl = $interval(function(){
          if (scope.t == 0) {
            scope.resetTimer();
            scope.sessionComplete = false;
          } else {
          scope.t -= 1;
          scope.displayTime()
          }
        },1000)
      }

      scope.toggleClass = function() {
      tDiv.toggleClass('notWorking working');
      }

    }
  };
}]);

app.directive('start', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    require: "^timer",
    templateUrl: '/templates/start.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, timerCtrl) {
      scope.startTimer = function() {
        if (tDiv.hasClass("notWorking")) {
          // scope.working = true;
          scope.interval(scope.t);
          scope.toggleClass();
        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="pomodoro_timer">
<head lang="en">
    <title>Pomodoro Timer</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <timer></timer>
  <start></start>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how you html structure looks like? Though your `scope.interval(scope.t)` should be `timerCtrl.interval(scope.t)`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `require: '^timer'` inside `start`, that means you are assuming that your `start` directive should be inside `timer` directive so that `start` directive can get access to the controller of `timer` directive.

Also you should place the expo-sable method inside controller rather than placing it into link function, controller could be accessible by the directive which require this controller.

**Markup**

```
<timer>
   <start></start>
</timer>
```

**Code**

```
app.directive("timer", ['$interval', function($interval) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.interval = function() {
                $scope.intrvl = $interval(function() {
                    if (scope.t == 0) {
                        $scope.resetTimer();
                        $scope.sessionComplete = false;
                    } else {
                        $scope.t -= 1;
                        $scope.displayTime()
                    }
                }, 1000)
            };
            $scope.toggleClass = function() {
                tDiv.toggleClass('notWorking working');
            };
        },
        templateUrl: "/templates/timer.html",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.intrvl = 0; //set default value
            scope.t = 10;
            var tDiv = $(element).find('#time');
            scope.min = "25";
            scope.sec = "00";
        }
    };
}]);

app.directive('start', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        require: "^timer",
        templateUrl: '/templates/start.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, timerCtrl) {
            scope.startTimer = function() {
                if (tDiv.hasClass("notWorking")) {
                    //calling method of `timer` directive controller
                    timerCtrl.interval(scope.t); 
                    timerCtrl.toggleClass();
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for effort, however, I'm getting the error scope is not defined. I tried passing it into the timer directive but then the page will not load.